# $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{n}$, where $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1+x_{n}^{\beta}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $0\leq\beta<1$. Prove the following series converges. $x_{1}=1$,
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_{n}$, where $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1+x_{n}^{\beta}}$

Hint says $x_{n}\leq\frac{C}{n^{\frac{1}{\beta}}}$.
But i can't show hint.
How to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: The case $\beta=0$ is clear, we suppose $\beta>0$. I leave too you the facts that $x_n>0$ for all $n$ and $x_n\to 0$. If $u\to 0$, we have $(1+u)^{\beta}-1\sim \beta u$. Put $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^{\beta}}$ and show that if $x>0, x\to 0$, then $\frac{1}{f(x)^{\beta}}-\frac{1}{x^{\beta}}\to \beta$. Now replace $x$ by $x_n$, and finally use Cesaro's Theorem.

Comment: What is the Cesaro's thm? Do you mean the following? : If $\{a_{n}\}$ is Cesaro summable and $a_{n}=O(1/n)$ , then $\sum a_{n}<\infty$

Comment: Cesaro 's theorem say that if $u_n\to L$, then $v_n=\frac{u_1+\cdots+u_n}{n}\to L$ also. If you do not want to use this result, say that $\frac{1}{x_{n+1}^{\beta}}-\frac{1}{x_n^{\beta}}\geq \beta/2$ for say $n\geq N$, and conclude that $\frac{1}{x_n^{\beta}}\geq an+b$ for some consrtants $a,b$ for $n$ large.

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you very much!